# OpenAPI Schema Nested Models (more than 1 level)

Tags: openapi, redoc

Using OpenAPI 3+ and Redoc, and having issues with references not working once I go more than one level deep, is there something i'm doing wrong or missing here?

`openapi.yaml`

```
components:
  schemas:
    $ref: components/schemas/_index.yaml
```

`components/schemas/_index.yaml`

```
AdminParticipants:
  $ref: ./admin/Participants.yaml
admin:
  $ref: "./admin/_index.yaml"
```

`components/schemas/admin/_index.yaml`

```
Participants:
  $ref: ./Participants.yaml
```

When trying to access the schema model using below reference it does not work (get `Invalid reference token: Participants` error)

```
$ref: "#/components/schemas/admin/Participants"
```

However this does work:

```
$ref: "#/components/schemas/AdminParticipants"
```

Is it not possible to create nested references more than one level deep for `schemas` or any other `components`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI does not actually support `$ref` directly under the `components.schemas` node. You can only `$ref` individual schemas or schema properties. Some tools might accept $refs in arbitrary places, but the behavior may vary.

Here's the version that will work with any OpenAPI-compliant tools:

```yaml
# openapi.yaml

components:
  schemas:
    AdminParticipants:
      $ref: ./admin/Participants.yaml
    AnotherSchema:
      $ref: ./path/to/schema.yaml
```

You'll can then reference these schemas as:

```yaml
$ref: '#/components/schemas/AdminParticipants'

$ref: '#/components/schemas/AnotherSchema'
```

The following will NOT work - not only because of non-standard `$ref` placement in `openapi.yaml`, but also because it would result in a wrong structure of the `schemas` section.

```yaml
# openapi.yaml

components:
  schemas:
    $ref: components/schemas/_index.yaml
```

```yaml
# components/schemas/_index.yaml

admin:
  $ref: "./admin/_index.yaml"
```

```yaml
# components/schemas/admin/_index.yaml

Participants:
  $ref: ./Participants.yaml
```

After dereferencing, the snippets above become:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    admin:
      Participants:
        type: object  # or however the schema is defined in 'Participants.yaml'
        ...
```

which has an extra key between the schema name and schema contents, so it's not valid OpenAPI.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you for the clarification, I guess I just assumed that schema's could be nested like that, I appreciate the thorough explanation and examples!

Comment: With that said though, are we expected to just have a huge file with all of the models and schemes in a single file then i guess?  Just seems hard to organize any large projects